# How can I repair a ceramic capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, motherboard, ceramic

This is an all-in-one Dell Inspiron One 2305. I received it for free because it was "having issues with the RAM." However, the power light was a solid amber when plugged in, and I was unable to manually turn it on or off (other than by disconnecting the power cable). I decided to bake the board, as it seems to consistently suffer from faulty soldering joints due to overheating. This did not solve the amber light, but I am now able to turn the computer on and off manually via the power button. The screen does not light up, and there are no POST beeps. Upon further inspection I discovered what appeared to be a blown ceramic capacitor (though I'm no electrical engineer, so I can't be certain). It was fairly dark and flaked away.  I wasn't able to salvage a part number from it. I'm not certain that this is the issue causing the amber light, but I thought it was a good possibility that it was playing a role in the situation.

I know it would be easier to just replace the board, but I've invested a good amount of time into trying to fix this computer - now I'm just curious if it can be fixed.

So, my real question: is it possible to fix a small ceramic capacitor like this, and how might I go about finding the correct type/value of the capacitor?[image][image]

Comment: You look it up in the schematic/BOM

Comment: Just put something of samw size. If it's not good, try something else. You have like five options between 1nF and 100uF. It looks like 1206, so start with 10uF

Comment: PlasmaHH I searched for a schematic. Apparently Dell doesn't release them, and I was unable to find one for this model. If you know of a place to find it, I would appreciate the resource.

Answer (score 1):

The damaged area looks like a mount pad for a (desoldered/fell off)
electrolytic capacitor.   The C490 designation indicates a capacitor,
the white bar indicates its polarity, and it is a smaller package than
the nearby electrolytic capacitor (also C1xx marked, but the
number is obscured by the component) that has a (+) marking
on top.

Not enough info to know what to put in its place, but typically
47uF/16V would be expected.   There's a LOOSE PART in the works,
which should be found and removed (and it might have a useful 
marking to guide replacement).

Comment: I believe the C490 designation is for the intact white capacitor next to the ferrite bead L59.  If there was a designation for the missing/destroyed component, I can't see it.  There is a diode designation nearby (D14), but it is really close to an unpopulated 3-terminal footprint.  The L47 may once have had a white line pointing to the footprint (like C473 does).

Comment: Alright, so it sounds like there's a possibility that it can be fixed through a bit of trial-and-error, correct? If so, I'll begin work!

Comment: @evildemonic I couldn't really make out a designation for it either. That's partly why I was a bit confused as to what the part was.

Comment: I found a picture of it:   https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/819t3YnawcL._SL1500_.jpg    looks like a diode.

Comment: On closer inspection, what I thought was a >| might actually be a K.  It also looks like a power resistor.   https://ssli.ebayimg.com/images/g/sOYAAOSwtBdafKaZ/s-l1600.jpg